# Add quotes to elemens of the list in jinja2 (ansible)

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have very simple line in the template:

```
ip={{ip|join(', ')}}
```

And I have list for ip:

```
ip:
 - 1.1.1.1
 - 2.2.2.2
 - 3.3.3.3
```

But application wants IPs with quotes (ip='1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2').

I can do it like this:

```
ip:
 - "'1.1.1.1'"
 - "'2.2.2.2'"
 - "'3.3.3.3'"
```

But it is very ugly. Is any nice way to add quotes on each element of the list in ansible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually there is a very simple method to achieve this:

```
{{ mylist | map('quote') | join(', ') }}
```

The filter `map` iterates over every item and let `quote` process it. Afterwards you can easily `join` them together.

Comment: the `quote` filter seems to be a part of ansible and not jinja2's core.

Comment: for some reason map('quote') never works for me in ansible, it does nothing

Comment: Ansible's `map('quote')` quotes for shell only

Comment: map('quote') quotes for shell variables (wont work for j2 templates), and it decides if quoting is needed (based on content of the string). Take Away: Use a for loop instead.

Comment: For the record, quoting works for the `command` module.

Answer (score 30):

This will work :

```
ip={{ '\"' + ip|join('\", \"') + '\"' }}
```

A custom filter plugin will also work. In ansible.cfg uncomment filter_plugins and give it a path, where we put this

```
def wrap(list):
    return [ '"' + x + '"' for x in list]

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'wrap': wrap
        }
```

in a file called core.py. [Like this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/runner/filter_plugins). Then you can simply use

```
ip|wrap|join(', ')
```

And it should produce comma seperated list with each ip wrapped in quotes.

Comment: This works like a charm. And if you want this just for one project / playbook, simply put a `filter_plugins` folder in your project and call the file, as already mentioned, `core.py`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ip={{ '\"' + ip|join('\", \"') + '\"'}}` ?

Answer (score 13):

try:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tags: s20
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ip:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 2.2.2.2
      - 3.3.3.3
    joined_ip: "'{{ \"', '\".join(ip)}}'"
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="(ip={{joined_ip}})"
```

PS: ansible supports a bit of python code execution within `{{}}`, which is what i'm misusing here.

Comment: This one works for me while the other not. Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in this blog: https://medium.com/opsops/how-enquote-list-elements-faab833e25fe

Use **to_json** filter. This will **double quote** every string of the list:

```
list_of_string | map("to_json")
```

The problem with the "quote" filter is that it does not quote elements that dont need to be quoted from a bash perspective (no space in the string). But for windows commands sometimes strings must be quoted anyway.

Comment: seems that the `to_json` has been changed to `tojson`

Comment: `list_of_string | tojson` is enough for a list of strings

Answer (score 6):

Following worked for me

```
('{{ iplist | join('\',\'') }}')
```

**Ex:**

```
Inventory

[ips]
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

#cat temp.sh.j2 

 "ips": (ip='{{ groups['zoo'] | join('\',\'') }}') 

result:

#cat temp.sh

 "ips": (ip='1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3')
```

Hope it would help someone.

Comment: works good for not empty list. but for empty array, it will result with ['']

Comment: If you want tp use double quotes (it's also a bit clear for me): `("{{ iplist | join('\",\"') }}")`

Answer (score 3):

I found the simplest way to do this with an existing Ansible filter is using `regex_replace`.

```
{{ ip | map("regex_replace","(.+)","\'\\1\'") | join(',')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE** This is similar to Kashyap's answer, but i needed a slightly different version: Using it to double quote each items in a bash array), eg. result should be:

`SOME_LIST=( "Johnny" "Joey" "Dee Dee" "Tommy" )`

projects/ansible/expand_list.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    some_list:
      - Johnny
      - Joey
      - Dee Dee
      - Tommy

  tasks:
    - name: "Expand the ramones band members list."
      template:
        src: "templates/expand_list.conf.j2"
        dest: "/var/tmp/ramones.conf"
```

projects/ansible/templates/expand_list.conf.j2

```
SOME_LIST=( "{{ '" "'.join(some_list) }}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a custom `wrap` filter

```
def wrap(value, wrapper = '"'):
  return wrapper + value + wrapper

class FilterModule(object):
  def filters(self):
    return {
      'wrap': wrap
    }
```

As you can see wrapper is customizable and defaults to `"`

You can use it this way

```
ip={{ ip | map('wrap') | join(', ') }}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm a python and ansible newbie

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex_replace`, f.e. in a j2 template file:

```
(ip={{ip | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', "'\\1'") | join(',')}})
```

If you do this inline in a play, do not forget to escape the double quotes. Here is a full example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ip:
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 2.2.2.2
    - 3.3.3.3
    ip_result: "{{ip | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', \"'\\1'\") | join(',')}}"
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="(ip={{ip_result}})"
  - copy: content="(ip={{ip_result}})" dest=./ip_result.txt
```

Content of ip_result.txt:

```
$ cat ip_result.txt
(ip='1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3')
```