# How to create dynamic list in yaml?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying to render a template. I have to create a list as

```
host:
- '111.222.333.444'
- '555.666.777.888'
```

which has to be taken from another host file.

I am using something like this:

```
{% for host in groups['hostgroup'] %}
host: {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
```

What is the correct way to achieve the result?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you wish to declare a variable in your inventory called host which contains a list of ip addresses, you can try:

```
host: {{ groups['hostgroup'] }}
```

Or you could skip declaring this variable and use `{{ groups['hostgroup'] }}` directly wherever you plan to use `{{ host }}`

Look at [add-quotes-join thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537684/add-quotes-to-elemens-of-the-list-in-jinja2-ansible) and this [filter plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/runner/filter_plugins/core.py#L137) if you want quotes.

**EDIT**:
Assuming you are rendering a template, using the ansible `template` module

```
host:
{% for host in groups['hostgroup'] %}
 - '{{ host }}'
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This gets me to
`host: ['111.222.333.444', '555.666.777.888']`
I want it in the format shown in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to initialize the `host` variable or are you rendering a template?

Comment: Rendering a template.

Comment: Edited my answer, but it seems too simple I guess your intent is different.

Comment: Silly of me to have _host:_ inside the for loop.