# How to build nested variable in Ansible role

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, ansible, amazon-vpc

I need to build role that automatically creates subnets for VPC based on amount of AZ defined.

```
- name: Setup "{{ aws.vpc.name }}" VPC
  ec2_vpc:
    state: present
    cidr_block: 172.20.0.0/16
    resource_tags: { "Name": "{{aws.vpc.name}}" }
    subnets:
      - cidr: 172.20.1.0/24
        az: us-east-1d
        resource_tags: { "Name": "{{aws.vpc.name}}-1d" }
      - cidr: 172.20.2.0/24
        az: us-east-1c
        resource_tags: { "Name": "{{aws.vpc.name}}-1c" }
    internet_gateway: True
    route_tables:
      - subnets:
          - 172.20.1.0/24
          - 172.20.2.0/24
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gw: igw
    region: {{ aws.vpc.region }}
```

How to generate automatically block like this one if I have only AZ name like

`aws.vpc.az = ['a', 'c', 'e']`

```
      - cidr: 172.20.1.0/24
        az: us-east-1d
        resource_tags: { "Name": "{{aws.vpc.name}}-1d" }
```

So, I have checked http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html. But I didn't find a way to generate this block dynamically

Comment: I feel confused with question. Do you intend to have a list variable `az` in dictionary `aws.vpc` for list of AZs, and then you want to dynamically access that list and perform this task over that list? If that's not what you mean, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you need another task that uses a loop to generate an Ansible list into a variable.  This can then be used in the main task:

```
- subnets: "{{ subnet_list }}"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29704897/992887) for an example using hosts.  Your case is more complex as each item in `subnet_list` is itself a dictionary (cidr, az, and resource_tags being the keys).