# Creating list of ip's in ansible using given range within jinja template

Tags: jinja2, ansible

i want to generate a list of ip addresses (using range of last 8bits so 120-190 translates to x.x.x.120 - x.x.x.190) in defaults/main.yml in my role, and later use it to create new network interfaces and generate a new config file. I tried this approach:

**defaults/main.yml:**

`ip_list: "{%for address_end in range(50,99)%} 192.168.0.{{address_end}}{%endfor%}"
conf_list: "{%for ip in ip_list%}server {{ip}}:6666 {%endfor%}"`

and then to use it in template

**template.conf.j2:**

```
{% for conf_line in conf_list %}
{{conf_line}}
{% endfor %}
```

and all i got in generated config file was:

```
            s
            e
            r
            v
            e
            r


            :
            6
            6
            6
            6

            s
            e
            r
            v
            e
            r

            1
            :
            6
```

so my guess is that i'm not generating a list but just a long string and when I use for loop in **template.conf.j2** I iterate over single chars. I tried using answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704728/how-to-create-dynamic-list-in-yaml) problem but all i got was syntax error. Any ideas for what might help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should format your vars as JSON lists if you want them to be lists.
`1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3` is a string.
`['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']` will be converted to list.

But there is alternative approach for you:

```
ip_list: "{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=50 count=12 format=192.168.0.%d', wantlist=True) }}"
conf_list: "{{ ip_list | map('regex_replace','(.*)','server \\1:6666') | list }}"
```

Comment: the alternative aproach seems cool, but out of curiosity how would one format vars as a JSON list in my case ?

Comment: follow my example list in the answer: place single quotes around ip-addresses, place comma after each address and place square brackets on both sides.

Comment: i get how JSON lists look like but i have problems with jinja templates syntax and i wanted to know if (and how) this is applicable in my case :)

Comment: `ips: "[{%for i in range(1,5)%}'192.168.0.{{i}}',{%endfor%}]"`

Comment: ^this just creates a string for me like in the example i posted. But the template code that you posted in your answer worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @Sackhorn Maybe you are passing it through the `list` filter? It is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Kostantin answer was of much help, but i found just realized that generating config entries in my case could be solved in an less complex way. Instead of trying to iterate over list or a string variable variable in jinja template file **template.conf.j2** like did with :

```
{% for conf_line in conf_list %}
{{conf_line}}
{% endfor %}
```

you could just enter insert new line signs while generating string in **defaults/main.yml**:

```
conf_list: "{%for ip in ip_list%}server {{ip}}:6666\n{%endfor%}"
```

and then just insert that whole string into a **template.conf.j2** like this:

```
{{conf_line}}
```

nevertheless i have no other idea how to generate list of ip addresses other than the one Konstantin proposed.